# Where storage node on zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I would checks value of node which storage on Zookeeper. 
Where storage nodes?
How i can see value of specific node?

I use ZooInspector for checks node name which storage on Zookeeper and use save node, but node don't save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it's help for someone.
You can checks node info on log files, they are locate on {zookeekeper_repository}/data/version-2/ in log4j format.

And for checks value of node exists util for Zookeeper - ZooInspector(https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/tree/b79af153d0f98a4f3f3516910ed47234d7b3d74e/src/contrib/zooinspector).